# Android PackageManger -- Exception

Tags: android, performance

When getting the list of packages which is running in devices, i am getting the execption proxy stub exception from my logcat

> **This  the code i used**
>   List packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
>
> **This the exception which im am getting**
>
> (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
>   "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
>   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ab1478 self=0x112f910
>   | sysTid=1801 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074439528
>   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=465 stm=85 core=1
>   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>   at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstalledApplications(IPackageManager.java:1930)
>   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getInstalledApplications(ApplicationPackageManager.java:414)
>   at com.informate.smnpd.DataUsageAppManager.processData1(DataUsageAppManager.java:237)
>   at com.informate.smnpd.DataUsageAppManager.processData(DataUsageAppManager.java:114)
>   at com.informate.smnpd.BackgroundService.getData(BackgroundService.java:667)
>   at com.informate.smnpd.ManualUpdate.onClick(ManualUpdate.java:221)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3526)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14133)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Can anyone please guide me on why this exception will occures at the time of getting installed package name. Thanks in advance

Comment: post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @raghav sood : ya i posted full stacktrace.

Comment: Your stack trace is not complete. I do not see what exception was thrown.

Comment: This is what im getting form logcat. does any device kills the Package Manager when trying to get list of installed packages ? or any permission has to set to overcome this issue.